# Alternative ways of defining zipWith using list comprehension without helper functions or extensions

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I know you can define `zipWith` with `zip` as:

> `zipwith' f xs ys = [f x y | (x,y) <- zip xs ys]`

But how about without `zip`? I read somewhere that you can do it with parallel list comprehension like this:

> `zipwith' f xs ys = [f x y | x <- xs | y <- ys]`

But you have to add `{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}` to the top of your code to make that work since it's an extension.

Are there any other ways of defining `zipWith` using list comprehension, preferably without helper functions or extensions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without making the comprehension O(n^2).

Comment: AFAIK, no.  By default list comprehension uses list's monad instance, in particular the `>>=` function, which is implemented using `concatMap`.  The [`ParallelListComp` extension instead desugars](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/5.00/set/parallel-list-comprehensions.html) `[f x y | x <- xs | y <- ys]` to `[f x y | (x, y) <- zip xs ys]`, and uses higher level `zip`s for more expressions.

Comment: @KennyTM How would you do it in O(n^2)?

Comment: `[f x y | (x, i) <- zip xs [0..], (y, j) <- zip ys [0..], i == j]` should work as an O(n^2) algorithm, but it still relies on `zip` to be implemented.  You could write a solution like `g [f x y | x <- xs, y <- ys]` where `g` drops the elements you don't care about, this would also be a significantly slower algorithm, but `g` would have to use `length`, `take`, and `drop`, and so this wouldn't work on infinite lists (neither will the indexed solution above).

Comment: Intuitively, this is impossible. `map`,`concat`, and `filter` descend recursively on just one list, while `zip` descends on both list arguments. At the moment I can't find any idea about how to prove this formally, though.

Comment: @user2108462: With `(!!)` and `length`. Well that may count as helper functions...

Comment: @kennytm `length` won't work for infinite lists and `!!` for the finite. I posted a solution using `takeWhile` and `drop` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without `zip` you have to use some – arguably basic – list access functions, viz., `drop` and `takeWhile`. Both are built-in, so, not "helper functions" that you wanted to avoid:

```
zipW :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipW f xs ys = [z | [z] <- takeWhile (not.null)                   
                             [z | [z] <- takeWhile (not.null)     -- ~ map (head.head)
    [ [ [c | (c:_) <- [drop i r]]                                 -- ~ take 1 . drop i
        | (r:_) <- [drop i rs]]                                   -- ~ take 1 . drop i
      | let rs = [[f x y | y<- ys] | x<- xs], i <- [0..]]]]
```

This recovers the diagonal from the Cartesian product, taking care to handle the  infinite lists (so, measuring their `length` is out of the question) as well as finite (so, `!!` can't be used).

> ~> zipW (,) [1..4] [10..] 
>   [(1,10),(2,11),(3,12),(4,13)] 
>    
>   ~> zipW (,) [1..] [10..13] 
>   [(1,10),(2,11),(3,12),(4,13)]

And of course it is quadratic, as long as `drop n` is *O(n)*, which it *usually* is.

If the lists are guaranteed to be infinite, it simplifies quite a bit into

```
zipWi f xs ys = [ rs !! i !! i | let rs = [[f x y | y<- ys] | x<- xs], i <- [0..]]
```

because using `!!` for list access is now okay (still quadratic, of course):

> ~> take 4 $ zipWi (,) [0..] [10..] 
>   [(0,10),(1,11),(2,12),(3,13)]

To make it linear, the recursive solution can be encoded with `unfoldr`, `iterate` etc., but not with the list comprehensions, I think.